# AdWords animated display ads - have 30 sec limit start on view?

Tags: google-ads

According to https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/answer/176108?hl=en, the total animation time for an ad needs to be kept to 30 sec, including looping.

When making an animated ad, I don't want it to start its 30 seconds of runtime when it's not visible and then when it's scrolled into view, then be done with its animation and be less effective.

Does anyone know if Google prevents ad animation from starting until it's in view, or if there's any way to accomplish this?  I saw a Google ad that appeared to not start its animation until scrolled into view so I think it must be possible somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Google is rolling out the ability to know whether or not ads are actually viewed.  They refer to this as "[Active View](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3499086?hl=en)".   You can pay *only* when your ad is actually show in the browser window (at least 50% visible for 1 second or more).

This also gives them the ability to start animation only once an ad becomes visible.

Unfortunately, not all placements are active view enabled yet.   Publishers need to update their ad tags to enable active view.

Comment: Will this automatically work for any ad which contains HTML5 animation or will it only work with their templated ones or through some special trick with custom ones?  Do you know of any documentation on Google which talks about Active View as it pertains to animated ads? Thanks

Comment: I was unable to find any documentation for any of that.